# Intercept SMS on Jailbroken iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4, sms, interceptor

I know that it is possible to do it, and I would like to know what private API's are available.  I understand it is not available for public API's and I am doing this as a hobby and am not going to submit.  Thanks

Comment: you can use this is link [http://stackoverflow.com/a/8120599/4731224](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8120599/4731224)
good louck

Answer (score 1):

CoreTelephony framework will do.